# Why is $12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (nk+i)$ (where $0 \le i < n$) an integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have been playing around with slices like this of $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ...$ e.g.
$1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ...$, or
$2 + 5 + 8 + 11 + ...$ using Dirichlet regularization in Mathematica and it seems the result is always an integer multiple of $1/12$.

Does anyone here have a hint why this would be the case?

Comment: Hmmm... Actually $12 \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (nk+i)$ is NOT an integer.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 1 \underset{\zeta}{=}\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n \underset{\zeta}{=} \zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$$
hence
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(kn+i) \underset{\zeta}{=} \color{red}{-\frac{k+6i}{12}}.$$

Comment: Here $$A\underset{\zeta}{=} B$$ means that the $\zeta$-regularization of $A$ equals $B$.